# Xamarin. Button. Как настроить положение текста в кнопке?

Tags: button, xamarin

Сразу говорю, что приложение кросс-платформенное. 
По умолчанию текст кнопки по середине. Как сделать, чтобы он был, например слева?
Нет параметра ни Alignment ни Padding ни Gravity..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[Тебе придется использовать Renderer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97460/how-to-align-button-text-to-the-left) и выравнивать текст на каждой платформе отдельно.